# .htaccess - Force www. throws ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, web

I am trying to force the www version of my site through the .htaccess file, but it throws me an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. Can you help me?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Access .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Errors
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
```

Thank you.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache

Comment: @starkeen the error is still there

Comment: Do you have any other rules in this htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen No, I have just what I posted here.

Comment: Shouldn't matter but your rewritebase is out of scope. It should be under the `RewriteEngine On`. Also I would put my 301 redirect rules first.

Comment: @PanamaJack It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you take out the www rule do you get errors?

Comment: @PanamaJack No, it works fine without it.

Comment: What type of system are you using? Like a CMS.  I suspect there is a config file for your website that has the site name declared without www. And it might be redirecting it back causing the loop. I've seen that before with some CMS'es.

Comment: @PanamaJack I don't have any CMS. I created the site from scratch.

Comment: @PanamaJack By the way, if it helps, if I type the www. url I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I hosted my website on OpenShift and added the domain with www as an alias and the domain without www as another alias.

The one with www was set as default. I set the one without www as default and it worked.

EDIT: It worked for a day and then it stopped working ...
Finally, I gave up and used this.

```
if(document.domain == "domain.com")
{
    window.location.replace("http://www.domain.com" + document.location.pathname + document.location.search);
}
```